# edit screen fields not populating in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I try to open an edit screen for relevant record when user taps the row in the list. I see at debugger all of the props are passing successfully but somehow I cant show them on the screen. I searched a lot and I think the main problem is at onRowPress helper. When I press the row, I see in the debugger all the props have passed correctly. But there is an error that says

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `array` supplied to
>   `TextInput`, expected `string`.

My question is how should I handle this error.

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPkWu.png)

```
 onRowPress() {
        console.log(this.props.employee);
        Actions.employeeEdit({ employee: this.props.employee });
      }
```

Comment: Where is the code to show edit form?

Comment: I added to the question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are on "The Complete React Native and Redux Course", if so, i thing you missed:

-1 `import Communications from "react-native-communications";`

-2

```
class EmployeeEdit extends Component {
  state = { showModal: false };
  ...
```

3- Above your `render()`:

```
onTextPress() {
  const { phone, shift } = this.props;

  Communications.text(phone, `Your upcoming shift is on ${shift}`);
}

onAccept() {
  const { uid } = this.props.employee;

  this.props.employeeDelete({ uid });
}

onDecline() {
  this.setState({ showModal: false });
}
```

-4 And finally, your main `render()` should be:

```
<Card>
  <EmployeeForm />

  <CardSection>
    <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Save Changes</Button>
  </CardSection>

  <CardSection>
    <Button onPress={this.onTextPress.bind(this)}>Text Schedule</Button>
  </CardSection>

  <CardSection>
    <Button onPress={() => this.setState({ showModal: !this.state.showModal })}>
      Fire Employee
    </Button>
  </CardSection>

  <Confirm
    visible={this.state.showModal}
    onAccept={this.onAccept.bind(this)}
    onDecline={this.onDecline.bind(this)}
  >
    Are you sure you want to delete this?
  </Confirm>
</Card>;
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes time but I solved the problem. Main problem was the error below;

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop value of type array supplied to 
>   TextInput, expected string.

I followed all the code step to step and find that the reducer which update the props with the values I pass can't do this. I added a toString() method to the actions.payload.value and everything is ok. You have to pass a string to the Input component.

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMPLOYEE_UPDATE:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value.toString() };
    case EMPLOYEE_CREATE:
      return INITIAL_STATE;
    case EMPLOYEE_SAVE_SUCCESS:
      return INITIAL_STATE;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```